# NPM start error - file path cannot find JSON package file

Tags: javascript, json, npm

First time poster, thanks in advance for the help!

I'm trying to complete my first project and am running into a few issues. The main one being that when I hit npm start I get hit with this error message -

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZXjV.png]

I've tried hitting npm install before I run it but to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas?!

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you make a `package.json` file in `C:\Users\Joshu\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\jamming`? If not, you should create a `package.json`.

Comment: What @Yousername said, Can you update your question to show the folder structure of `C:\Users\Joshu\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\jamming`?

Comment: i believe the command you should input when you first start up a project is `npm init` not `npm start`.

Comment: hey @AleksandarMisich, I've added additonal images in the post  to show the new error i'm getting after I did npm init / npm start and pictures showing the folder structure. 

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: can you post the content of you `package.json`

Comment: Hey @jd487, man you are running npm start command from`C:\Users\Joshu\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\jamming` folder, you need to run it in `C:\Users\Joshu\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\jamming\jamming`.

Answer (score 2):

Without the contents of the `package.json` I can only guess... As some of the comments have pointed our as well, make sure your `node` or `npm` command can navigate to/see your script file

---

### Context:

But there are 2 concepts here. `node` & `npm`

**1. Node is a runtime:**

In order to run a node script you'll need the `node` command (within the context of the project your working on, so make sure your cli is in the root of your project) like this:

```
node ./folder/to/your-script.js
```

**2. NPM is a package manager.**

...and it relies on having a `package.json` in the same directory as where you're running the `npm` command for most of it's commands other than `init` (which creates the `package.json` file for you)

---

### Problem:

The second screenshot is the clue here.

You tried running `npm start`, where the error message is:

> missing script: start

This means that your [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values) block does not contain a `start` property

Thus it seems to me as if you are mixing the 2 concepts.

1. If you wanted to run the script without a `package.json` you can use the `node <filename.js>` command
2. If you have dependencies, and want to make your life a little more
   convenient if you have a lot of other commands and dependencies, you
   can use the `npm run <script>` command.

(Side-note: `npm start` is a
    special case that seems to be able to run or without the `run`
    keyword, which I didn't know as well until I just tested it now :P)

---

### Solution:

Therefor to get closer to what your expecting, we can modify the `package.json` as per below:

You can also create custom aliases for commands within the `scripts` block (inside the `package.json`):

```
 "scripts": {
   "start": "node ./some-path/to/your-script.js"
   "bar": "npm run foo",
   "foo": "node ./folder/to/your-script.js"
 }
```

You'll notice, you can reference sibling script aliases in other script commands as well (you can also add non node commands in here, like `git`, etc..)

Thus with the above in your `package.json` you'll have access to the following commands when running `npm` in the same directory as the `package.json`.

`npm start`, `npm run foo` or `npm run bar`